# Upload html2pdf generated pdf file on s3 bucket by form data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular8

My current script is

```
exportPDF(id) {
const options = {
  filename: 'INV' + id + '.pdf',
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 2, dpi: 300,
    letterRendering: true,
    useCORS: true
  },
  jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
}
var element = document.getElementById('export-content');
var d = html2pdf().from(element).set(options).save();

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', d);

// Service for upload file in s3 bucket
this._uploadService.upload('invoice', formData).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
}, (error: any) => { 
  console.log(error, 'error');
});}
```

I want to store this generated pdf file to s3 bucket, and from s3 i want to sent on email via attachment. I dont want to store any blob data on db, just want to store s3 url in db. Please give a help.

Thanks in advance.

Found some solution for that by converting blob string to file but not able to store response string in global variable for converting in file and send via api call.

```
this.blobString: any;
html2pdf().from(element).set(options).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function (res) {
  this.blobString = res;

 // Service for upload file in s3 bucket
 this._uploadService.upload('invoice', this.blobString).subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
 }, (error: any) => { 
   console.log(error, 'error');
 });

});
console.log(this.blobString);
```

Getting undefind in console. Or how to set Worker data in global.

Answer (score 1):

your are working with promises, your console.log triggers before promise response change it as like this:

```
this.blobString: any;
html2pdf().from(element).set(options).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function (res) {
  this.blobString = res;
  console.log(this.blobString);
});
```

Comment: this.blobString getting undefined in console, i need to access this this.blobString in another function

Comment: @SurajParise then call the function after console.log(this.blobString); the above code works for me, I do not get undefined in console.

Comment: I tried like this also, see my updated question, write inside function, but getting error this._uploadService.upload is undefined.